# How can I set a variable the value of a date I type in using Python

Tags: variables, date

I have a variable called Y which i need the value to be any date I type in but I'm unsure how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [strptime()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)? It lets you parse a string into a date value.